# i'm getting loss = nan and accuracy = 0 for classification using LSTM, keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, multiclass-classification

I'm Trying motion classification using lstm.
this is my model

```
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], trainy.shape[1]
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
    # model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    # model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return loss, accuracy


for r in range(repeats):
    loss, score = evaluate_model(trainx, trainy, testx, testy)
    score = score * 100.0
    print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
    print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, loss))
```

this is my output

```
>#1: 0.000
>#1: nan
>#2: 0.000
>#2: nan
>#3: 0.000
>#3: nan
>#4: 0.000
>#4: nan
>#5: 0.000
>#5: nan
>#6: 0.000
>#6: nan
>#7: 0.000
>#7: nan
>#8: 0.000
>#8: nan
>#9: 0.000
>#9: nan
>#10: 0.000
>#10: nan
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Accuracy: 0.000% (+/-0.000)
```

where did I go wrong? I have seen some regression models get nan loss but I'm using a classification model.
is it because of my data?

[these are the sizes of test and train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNvog.png)

Comment: Could you please add information in your question about why the output you're receiving is wrong? It helps others provide more useful answers if you explain why the things you are doing are not producing the desired or expected outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data.

Your model wirks well on random data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], trainy.shape[1]
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    #model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return loss, accuracy


for r in range(5):
    trainx = tf.random.uniform([10, 10, 10])
    trainy = tf.random.uniform([10, 10])
    testx = tf.random.uniform([10, 10, 10])
    testy = tf.random.uniform([10, 10])
    loss, score = evaluate_model(trainx, trainy, testx, testy)
    score = score * 100.0
    print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
    print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, loss))
```